# Elastic Search error

Tags: maven, elasticsearch

I 'm intending to fix bugs on Elastic Search open-source project. I forked it and cloned the forked copy . Then I imported it as Maven project on Eclipse and then did Maven build . So far so good. 
I opened ElasticSearchF.java file and tried to run it as a Java application.(This is as per directions written in http://www.lindstromhenrik.com/debugging-elasticsearch-in-eclipse/).

But I get an error saying path.home is not set for ElasticSearch and throws an error saying IllegalStateException.

My question is

1. Why is this error coming in the first place.
2. As I said , I want to fix bugs in ElasticSearch project.Is this the right way to set-up environment for my goal? Or should I have a client send the requests  to the ElasticSearch server and then set-up debug points in Elastic Search source code. How to achieve this?

Thanks for your patience.

Update:
I did add VM argument as mentioned by one of the answerers.

Then it throws different errors and clue-less about why  its throwing that.

```
java.io.IOException: Resource not found: "org/joda/time/tz/data/ZoneInfoMap" ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@29578426
    at org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoProvider.openResource(ZoneInfoProvider.java:210)
    at org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoProvider.<init>(ZoneInfoProvider.java:127)
    at org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoProvider.<init>(ZoneInfoProvider.java:86)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.getDefaultProvider(DateTimeZone.java:514)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.getProvider(DateTimeZone.java:413)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID(DateTimeZone.java:216)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.getDefault(DateTimeZone.java:151)
    at org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology.getInstance(ISOChronology.java:79)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils.getChronology(DateTimeUtils.java:266)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.selectChronology(DateTimeFormatter.java:968)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.printTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:672)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.printTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:560)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.print(DateTimeFormatter.java:644)
    at org.elasticsearch.Build.<clinit>(Build.java:53)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:138)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:157)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:177)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:278)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticsearchF.main(ElasticsearchF.java:30)
[2015-06-16 18:51:36,892][INFO ][node                     ] [Kismet Deadly] version[2.0.0-SNAPSHOT], pid[2516], build[9b833fd/2015-06-15T03:38:40Z]
[2015-06-16 18:51:36,892][INFO ][node                     ] [Kismet Deadly] initializing ...
[2015-06-16 18:51:36,899][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Kismet Deadly] loaded [], sites []
{2.0.0-SNAPSHOT}: Initialization Failed ...
- ExceptionInInitializerError
    IllegalArgumentException[An SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat with name 'Lucene50' does not exist.  You need to add the corresponding JAR file supporting this SPI to your classpath.  The current classpath supports the following names: [es090, completion090, XBloomFilter]]
```

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#contributing-code-and-documentation-changes

Comment: @user4654 did you figure out the fix ?

Comment: @user4654 did you figure out the fix ? I am also facing the same error

Answer (score 3):

I got help from the developer community in https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/12737 and was able to debug it.

procedure in short would be :

1) Search for the file Elasticsearch.java/ElasticsearchF.java inside the package org.elasticsearch.bootstrap .

2) Right click -> Run Configurations...

3) In the window that pops up , Click the "Arguments" tab and under "Program arguments:" section give the value as start 
and under "VM arguments:" section give the value as
-Des.path.home={path to your elasticsearch code base root folder}/core -Des.security.manager.enabled=false

4) Click "Apply" and then click "Run".

It runs now.
to check , go to localhost:9200 and you will get a message something like

```
 {
  "name" : "Raza",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.0.0-beta1",
    "build_hash" : "${buildNumber}",
    "build_timestamp" : "NA",
    "build_snapshot" : true,
    "lucene_version" : "5.2.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

for more info on arguments 
see : https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/2b9ef26006c0e4608110164480b8127dffb9d6ad

Answer (score 0):

Edit your debug/run configurations,put it on the vm arguments:

-Des.path.home=C:\github\elasticsearch\

change the C:\github\elasticsearch\ to your elasticsearch root path

the reason is some arguments in the elasticsearch.bat is missed when you debug/run it in eclipse

Comment: I did the same:  I have an empty config folder inside the root folder. Then its throwing FileNotFoundException. Then I added two configuration files from a different installation to fix that. Then it throws different errors and clue-less about why  its throwing that.

Comment: The reason is a wrong Env variables and classpath. I set the ES_HOME ES_HEAP_SIZE ES_MAX_MEM ES_MIN_MEM in User Variables. The ES_HOME = yourpath/core. My ES is 1.6.0. In Debug Configurations, I set the VM arguments is -Delasticsearch -Des-foreground=yes -Des.path.home=C:\Self\github\elasticsearch\